# How to change your XCode iTunes Connect login?

Tags: iphone, xcode, loader, organizer

I am using several accounts to manage my customers iPhone/iPad applications. Therefore I need to connect to **iTunes Connect** with different logins. How can I change the login in **XCode** or **Application Loader**? It is always set to one default value that I probably entered the first time XCode was started.

When it comes to validating or submitting an application using the **XCode Organizer** I start to hate Apple for what they have done to use developers. In those situations I feel like a worm inside an Apple, pretty lost. The problem is that clicking on one of those buttons (Validate... or Submit...) is NOT giving ANY kind of feedback except in rare occations. The only way to see what is happening is using **Console** to see XCode log messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to change your itunes connect details in XCode. As long as you set the correct bundle identifier you can use a certificate from any provisioning portal and you can build your application against any developer account fine.

To change your log in details in application loader you have to go Window -> Run setup wizard... and re-enter your log in details. Then you can choose File -> New and it should find any waiting apps in the account you've just set up.

Comment: Window -> Run setup wizard... is the correct way. Thx Thomas.

Answer (score 14):

I don't see any answers that pertain to the XCode portion of the following question in the original post: "How can I change the login in **XCode** or **Application Loader**?"

This was significant for me as I have multiple Apple Dev IDs. When setting up a new MBP I needed to Refresh my Provisioning Profiles in the XCode Devices panel. The Refresh button uses the daw2.apple.com Web form password saved in your Keychain if you select the Remember Password in Keychain option on the "Sign in with your Apple ID" dialog. I had done so, which was preventing the downloading of provisioning profiles from my other accounts. Furthermore, the Refresh button uses cached credentials if you Refresh again after entering your Apple ID, even if you haven't selected the Keychain option.

So to Refresh multiple Apple ID provisioning profiles in XCode either:

1. Don't use the Keychain option to save your credentials and restart XCode for each Apple ID  that you want to download refreshed provisioning profiles.
2. If you have saved credentials in the Keychain and you need to use a different Apple ID, remove the Keychain login item for daw2.apple.com and restart XCode.

Comment: On XCode Version 4.4.1 this was the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I found out to change my **iTunes Connect** login is using **Keychain Access**. Simply hit Cmd + Spacebar and search for **Keychain Access**. Launch that application and enter "itunes" in the search bar of **Keychain Access**. Choose "All Items" in Category. Delete all items that are found. Now restart XCode or Application Loader, whatever you need to use. It should be asking you for a login again!

Answer (score 1):

A good method to keep Keychain Certificates, XCode settings and provision profiles, and Safari Developer portal logins completely separated is to use a separate Mac User Login account for each different client (and developer login).  This also helps keep customer IP cleanly separated.  If you need to login and show an account to a customer (Simulator demo, etc.), they won't see any IP from other customers.

You can check any of your common code out of a shared version control repository into each account as needed.  You can also use the Mac's fast user switch for working among the several accounts.

Comment: good idea! but that's just really annoying to switch the account all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is finally a way to make this work while preserving your sanity in Xcode 6.3.2.

The main trick is to make sure that your iTunes Connect account and Member Center account Apple id's are the same for any particular organization. It looks like Xcode assumes that and tries to use the Member Center Apple ID to access iTunes Connect.

Make sure and use a "+folder" style of email address to avoid creating and managing a whole bunch of real email accounts (see this for more info: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26053/gmail-address-with-within-the-recipient-name). But here's the crucial part - add that "+folder" style account to Member Center (i.e. invite the "+folder" account) for that organization and remove your plain Apple ID if you were using it there.

I.e. *don't use Member Center's ability to associate multiple organizations with one account*. That will just confuse Xcode if you also need to access multiple iTunes Connect accounts. Use one "+folder" account for each organization you are working with and add that Apple ID to both iTunes Connect and Member Center.